# Find the data related to a list of elements from a collection in MongoDB using python

Tags: python, mongodb, list, find

I have a list of SensorIDs (lstSensorList).

I'm going to fetch the data related to all these sensorIDs from a collection (TimeSeries) in MongoDB.

I can fetch the data related to a particular element in the list using the below code.

```
strSensorID = lstSensorList[0]

all_data = collection_TimeSeries.find({\
'SensorId': strSensorID,\
'Control':'LOG'\
})
```

But how do I filter the data related to all the sensorIDs with my list in python?

Comment: Is [the `$in` operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, it's similar to this. But how i find all the elements in the list without specifying particular elements

Comment: `'SensorId': { $in: lstSensorList }`? If not, can you edit your question to clarify what you have and what you are trying to get